# Selection of soldiers in which at least two adjacent soldiers are selected

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

20 soldiers are standing in a row and their captain want to send 7 out of them for a mission in how many ways can captain select them such that at least one soldier and the soldier next to him is also selected?

The selection of 7 soldiers can be done in 20C7 ways....what is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to subtract the number of selections of $7$ where *none* of the selected soldiers are next to each other. To figure out that number, you can use stars and bars:

$$.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.$$

The stars are the  $13$ soldiers that don't get selected, ans so the $7$ soldiers have to be a selection of the $14$ possible positions between them and at the ends. So, there are

$$14 \choose 7$$

selections where no two soldiers are next to each other.